# many to many insert from one form/controller method to all three tables - author, book & author_book in laravel

Tags: laravel

Succesfully inserted to author and book table but unable to insert in pivot table. I need to insert from the same form in all the 3 tables. I have attached screenshot of all of my code. Pls help.

**Book Model**

```
class Book extends Model
{
  protected $guarded = [];

  public function authors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Author');
  }
}
```

**Author Model**

```
class Author extends Model
{
  public $guarded = [];

  public function books(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Book');
  }
 }
```

**Book Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Book::create($this->validateBookInputs());
    Author::create($this->validateAuthorInputs());

    $book_id=Book::latest()->first()->id;
    // $author_id=Author::latest()->first()->id;

    // $book = new Book();
    // $book->authors()->attach($author_id);

    $author = new Author();
    $author->books()->attach($book_id);
    return back()->with('status', 'Insert Successful!');
}

public function validateBookInputs(){
    return request()->validate([
        'book_name' => 'required'
    ]);
}
public function validateAuthorInputs(){
    return request()->validate([
        'author_name' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

**Book Create - View**

```
<form action="/books" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Enter Book Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="book_name" placeholder="Book Name" value="{{old('book_name')}}" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Enter Author Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="author_name" placeholder="Author Name" value="{{old('author_name')}}"
        class="form-control">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="button-green">Submit</button>
@csrf
```

**create authors table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('author_name', '30');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**create books table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('book_name', '30');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**create author_book table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('author_book', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('author_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('book_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**The Error**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'author_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `author_book` (`author_id`, `book_id`) values (?, 25))
```

Comment: is author_id the current authorized user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the error in your controller store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Book::create($this->validateBookInputs());
    Author::create($this->validateAuthorInputs());

    $book_id=Book::latest()->first()->id;

    $author = new Author(); // <----
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    $author->books()->attach($book_id);

    return back()->with('status', 'Insert Successful!');
}
```

Here, you are creating a new instance of `Author`, not using the newly created author object. That's why is throwing an error: the new instance doesn't have an id yet (because it just exist in memory, it isn't persisted yet).

Update the code like so:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $book = Book::create($this->validateBookInputs());
//  ^^^^^^^  
    $author = Author::create($this->validateAuthorInputs());
//  ^^^^^^^ 

    $author->books()->attach($book->id); // <---
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    return back()->with('status', 'Insert Successful!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

problem is in BookController method store because use a new instance of Author model that not exists in database and just it is a instance of Author model, so change store method like following:

```
$book = Book::create($this->validateBookInputs());
$author = Author::create($this->validateAuthorInputs());

$author->books()->attach($book->id);
return back()->with('status', 'Insert Successful!');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid attaching step and go from 3 to two steps

```
$book = Book::create($this->validateBookInputs());
$author = $book->authors()->create($this->validateAuthorInputs())
```